# Create persistent connection between android and Apache Server

Tags: java, http, sockets, tcp, persistent-connection

i need to create a communication between an Android phone (Java), and a server running apache.
What i'm going to do, requires a lot of messages going and comming, and i don't know exacly "what to search", that will do this job.
Maybe the name is Persistent Connection, maybe socket... but i think that one of you will know what i should do.
My Code on the Android phone needs to receive constant data (at a rate of 1 or 2 secconds), and send at a rate of 5 secconds (for example).
Should i use a simple Webserver in my server, to do that stuff, and every time open a http page with post and get data, and receive json`s, or there is a more easy and efficient way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: If it needs to be over HTTP, check out [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: it doesen`t needs to be over anything... just something supported by Android and Apache (PHP) =]